# updatepanel.update issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have two nested updatepanels I update the panels from the source code but nothing takes effect. the code is following

```
<div style="display:block; clear: left;" runat="server" id="DivLike">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelLike" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLike" runat="server" CommandName='<%#Eval("Like_Command") %>'
                    Font-Size="XX-Small" OnCommand="LinkButton2_Command" Text='<%#Eval("Like_Command")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <div class="popupstyle" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:none;"
                id="DivChapters" runat="server">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div>Select Chapter:
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListChapters" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListChapters_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div>Select Topic:
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTopics" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAddLink" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButtonAddLink_Command"
                                Text="Add" CssClass="UtilityClass"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressLinkActivity" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity"
                            DynamicLayout="True">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                    <div style=" position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; background-color:white;"
                                    id="divLoading">
                                        <img src="Images/loading25.gif" alt="Loading..." style="" />
                                    </div>
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonAddLink" EventName="Command"
                            />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonLike" EventName="Command"
            />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Code Behind below updates the panels but none of the panel is updated. though when I analyze it with debugger every thing is assigned perfectly.

```
 protected void DropDownListChapters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e )
 {
    DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)sender;
    DropDownListTopics.DataSource = ChapterDataAccess.GetUserTopics(Convert.ToInt32(DDL.SelectedItem.Value), new Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()));
    DropDownListTopics.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownListTopics.DataValueField = "Id";
    DropDownListTopics.DataBind();
    ListItem item=new ListItem ("topics","value" );
    DropDownListTopics.Items.Add(item);
    UpdatePanel thepanel= (UpdatePanel)DDL.Parent.Parent;
    UpdatePanel theparentpanel=(UpdatePanel)DDL.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent ;
    theparentpanel.Update();
    thepanel.Update();


}
```

Comment: this code is inside the gridview's itemtemplate.

Comment: remove the update panels, and try to see if you get any error, then maybe use only one update panel

Comment: What if the error arise? Using nested panel is the necessity not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are accessing the Update Panels properly..

When the UpdatePanels are not enclosed inside another Content Placeholders , I think you can directly access the Update Panels instead of using the parent to find it..

Simply

```
UpdatePanelLinkActivity.Update();
UpdatePanelLike.Update() ;
```

should do..

Comment: Hi!I would be very glad if I could do this. They are inside the GridView Row.Sorry did not mention that in the Question.

Comment: I get the update panel nicely when i check with debugger but when the update is applied then nothing happens.